# OrientDB: sigsegv (0xb) when insert large amount of records

Tags: java, orientdb

[image: error description]

I was trying to insert 1 million records into OrientDB, and this problem bothered me a lot.

I thought it might be related to file size, but when I dealt with a file bigger than 300MB, it works fine.

Only when I tried to insert a file the size of which was bigger than 800MB, did it detect the error.

I have tried to split the file into 10 files, and process them one by one, but it still failed while dealing with the 7th one.

I googled it, which told that there is no limit of file size in orientDB.

Besides, none of my records is larger than 2GB.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How much memory do you have? If you can allocate, for example, 4 GB to OrientDB, I suggest to allocate 25% of JVM Heap and the rest to the OrientDB DiskCache (size in MB).

To do this open bin/server.sh script and modify last line setting these settings:

`java -Xmx=1G -Dstorage.diskCache.bufferSize=3000`

Another advice: upgrade to last v. 1.7.6, by overwriting the jars under OrientDB's lib directory and restart it.

Comment: My total memory is 4GB, together with some other uses. I've modified the settings, and new problem appears. It tells that "Out of memory".

Comment: Out Of Memory means the heap is too low. What kind of operations are you executing to give that error?

Comment: I was trying to insert a large amount of records. Now I've updated to v. 1.7.6, shall I still modify the setting?

Comment: Same settings like before.

Comment: Still not work. But after spliting the data into several one and rebooting the server after each inserting, I finally succeeded in inserting the data.